# WCFTestClient ConnectionString Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a WCF service that works perfectly when I use it from my Emulator or when I run from my Nokia 520 through VS2013 debug.

I'm facing errors when I try to connect without VS2013 debug, and now I'm trying to use WCFTestClient to test my WCF service.

When I click in any method of my service, I receive this error:

```
No connection string named 'SegurancaEntities' could be found in the application config file.
```

In my service app.config I have this connectionstring as I show here:

```
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="false" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
          logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
  </diagnostics>
  <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="basicBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Metadata" name="WCFDataLibrary.EnvioDados">
          <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" contract="WCFDataLibrary.IEnvioDados" />
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="http://vm-2008-srv/WCFDataService/EnvioDados" />
              </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        <!--<identity>
          <dns />
        </identity>-->
      </service>
  </services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Metadata">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://vm-2008-srv/WCFDataService/meta" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SegurancaEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=vm-2008-srv;initial catalog=Seguranca;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Why I can't run the WCFTestClient on my service ?

Comment: @Belogix I'm sorry but I didn't understand your comment. In the WCFTestClient I'm adding the service with the address of the service (IIS Hosted): http://10.120.186.164/wcfdatasite/EnvioDados.svc

Comment: Okay, so the error is actually returned from the service saying it cannot find the connection string for your database (I assume)?

Comment: Exactly! But it's strange because if I run the program from my WP8 Emulator it's run without error! The error is just occurs when I run the WTC and I'm facing an error when I run the WP8 app outside VS2013 (directly from the device) so I'm trying desperately find the reason of the error because the error returned from the exception not allows me to understand what is really going on (The remote server returned an error: Notfound)!